# How to use articles, taxonomy, views, and filters to set up a content navigation scheme?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

Right off the bat, I'd like to let everyone know that I'm brand new to Drupal, and while I've been making progress using the excellent short video tutorials on LevelUp Tutorials, I'm missing some concepts.  Here's my use case:

**Drupal 7**

I'm using a taxonomy to establish the relationship between NCAA football teams, their respective conferences, and the names of their stadiums.  It looks like this:

Name: NCAA 1A Conferences

```
SEC
-Missouri
--Faurot Field
-Ole Miss
--Vaught-Hemingway Stadium
-South Carolina
--Williams-Brice Stadium ...
```

and so on.

I'm attempting to set this up so that I can:

1. Use the team names as a field in an "Event" article (Home Team or Away Team)
2. Automatically populate a block on my custom home page with the home team's stadium. The block is a view that pulls the 2 closest "Event" articles (games) and displays the "Event" title, time remaining until event, number of comments on the event, and hopefully the stadium in a tabular format.
3. Create a url alias scheme similar to:    ncaa/sport/conference/school
   and create pages at each level.

> ncaa/football/

would eventually return a view with a table of the conferences and their respective teams, linking both to

> ncaa/football/division/conference/ 
>   and
>   ncaa/football/division/conference/school

which would display links to the respective schools or the school's information and game schedule, etc.

4. Create a menu and/or filter that displays in sidebar 1 (or anywhere, really) that would allow users to filter through created events based on their relationships to the items in this taxonomy.

Were I coding this from scratch myself, I'd probably already be done with it, but I really want to get a good grasp of Drupal and develop an understanding of the core concepts.

Now, I understand that there is a lot here, and I don't expect anyone to hold my hand through the entire process.  I need help understanding how and why to use articles, taxonomy, views, etc. in such a way to accomplish these tasks.  It may be that I'm approaching this problem in a very non-Drupal fashion, and I'd really appreciate someone talking me through that bit.

Bottom line: Don't give me a fish, help me make a fishing pole.  I'd like to accomplish as much of this as possible without installing a bunch of extra modules so that I learn to get the most our of the core functionality.  I've already got Chaos Tools, IMCE, CKEditor, Views, Webform, Pathauto, Calendar, and Context.
Thanks very much, and please let me know if you need any more information.